# How to implement a "workqueue" in python?

Tags: python

I would like to run hundreds of Python programs in a desktop with 12 cores, and if I run all of them at the same time, I would probably use up the memory.  I am wondering what are some good ways to implement a "workqueue" in Python, such that it could make sure that there are always n (might be a value from 10 to 12) programs running while others are waiting in the queue.  When one of them finishes, the "workqueue" runs another program in the queue.

Currently what I am thinking is I could use a file to store the waiting list, and monitor running programs using their process id, but it seems not so efficient, so I would like to know whether there are better ways to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool` is an option.

Comment: @tdelaney  Does it run all programs in parallel at the same time?

Comment: @username123 are these "programs" cpu intensive?

Comment: @tijko I think so.  And they require lots of memory.

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) but yes. Pools run functions in your program in multiple processes so if your workers are just functions, it works well. If your workers are other programs, you can write a function that runs those programs via `subprocess`.